# Iterating over a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

I have been diligently watching YouTube videos in an effort to understand linked lists before my fall classes start and I am uncertain how to proceed with iterating over the following linked list. The 'node' class is from a series of videos (same author), but the 'main' method was written by me. Am I approaching the design of a linked list in an illogical fashion (assuming of course one does *not* wish to use the predefined LinkedList class since the professor will expect each of us to write our own implementation)?:

```
class Node
{
    private String data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(String data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setData(String d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }

    public static String getThird(Node list)
    {
        return list.getNext().getNext().getData();
    }

    public static void insertSecond(Node list, String s)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(s, list.getNext());
        list.setNext(temp);
    }

    public static int size(Node list)
    {
        int count = 0;

        while (list != null)
        {
            count++;
            list = list.getNext();
        }

        return count;
    }
}

public class LL2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node n4 = new Node("Tom", null);
        Node n3 = new Node("Caitlin", n4);
        Node n2 = new Node("Bob", n3);
        Node n1 = new Node("Janet", n2);

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Caitlin

Comment: You have just nodes here. You have to implement a list, which holds the first and the last node and also the size. You need at least the following classes: Node; NodeList.

Comment: Here is only just Node class where is the List class?? you are mixing them both i think you didn't understand properly linked list.

Comment: Have a look here how to implement it with Node and NodeList:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations

Comment: Who says a list needs more than a node? In LISP & Co a list is just a node: a single node is a one-element list, a node having a value and pointing to another node is a two-elemet list ... and so on. Conceptually there's nothing that requires a separate entity. It's a useful place to "cache" information (such as the length) and to put some useful methods, but it's not inherent to the concept of a "linked list" IMHO.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Totally agree. This is also how a linked list is represented in some (often language agnostic) books about data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some flaws in your linked list as stated by some of the other comments. But you got a good start there that grasps the idea of a linked list and looks functional. To answer your base question of how to loop over this particular implemention of the linked list you do this

```
Node currentNode = n1; // start at your first node
while(currentNode != null) {
    // do logic, for now lets print the value of the node
    System.out.println(currentNode.getData());
    // proceed to get the next node in the chain and continue on our loop
    currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be useful:

```
static void iterate(Node head) {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.getData());
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}

// or through recursion
static void iterateRecursive(Node head) {
    if (head != null) {
       System.out.println(head.getData());
       iterateRecursive(head.getNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class List {        
    Item head;

    class Item {        
        String value;  Item next;   
        Item ( String s ) { value = s; next = head; head = this; }
    }

    void print () {
        for( Item cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.next ) 
            System.out.println ( cursor.value );
    }

    List () {
        Item one = new Item ( "one" );
        Item two = new Item ( "three" );
        Item three = new Item ( "Two" );
        Item four = new Item ( "four" );
    }
}

public class HomeWork {
    public static void main( String[] none ) {  new List().print();  }
}
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your linked list DS class implement 'Iterable' interface and override hasNext(), next() methods or create an inner class to do it for you. Take a look at below implementation:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T>{
private Node<T> head;
public SinglyLinkedList(){
    head = null;
}

public void addFirst(T item){
    head = new Node<T>(item, head);
}
public void addLast(T item){
    if(head == null){
        addFirst(item);
    }
    else{
        Node<T> temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new Node<T>(item, null);
    }
}

private static class Node<T>{
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;
    public Node(T data, Node<T> next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T>{
    private Node<T> nextNode;
    public LinkedListIterator(){
        nextNode = head;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (nextNode.next != null);
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        T result = nextNode.data;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
        return result;
    }

}
```

}